# "ὑμᾶς νεκροὺς ὄντας -you being dead" (Col 2:13) - What does “being dead" (fig.) imply, a complete or partial inanimate state of us?

Tags: word-study, colossians

*Col 2:13** - "And you -- being dead in the trespasses and the uncircumcision of your flesh -- He made alive together with him, having forgiven you all the trespasses" (YTL).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of being "dead in your sins" is a common metaphor in the NT:

- Eph 2:5 - made us alive with Christ even when we were **dead in transgressions**--it is by grace you have been saved. See also V1.
- Col 2:13 - When you were **dead in your trespasses** and in the uncircumcision of your sinful nature, God made you alive with Christ. He forgave us all our trespasses,
- Luke 15:32 - But it was fitting to celebrate and be glad, because this **brother of yours was dead** and is alive again; he was lost and is found.’ ” See also VV24
- Rom 6:11 - So you too must count yourselves **dead to sin**, but alive to God in Christ Jesus. See also V13
- Rev 3:1 - These are the words of the One who holds the seven Spirits of God and the seven stars. I know your deeds; you have a reputation for being alive, **yet you are dead**.

The operative word here is νεκρός (nekros = "dead").  This word can mean:

- literally dead/ lifeless, eg, Acts 28:6, Acts 5:10, James 2:26, etc
- spiritually dead while being physically alive, eg, as listed above.

The second meaning is defined more clearly by BDAG as:

> *pertaining to being so morally or spiritually deficient as to be in effect dead*

Comment: agreed. I'd add that there is also a statement here that the Colossians were 'dead' because they were physically uncircumcised... not part of the people of God. Their conversion both enabled them to be forgiven of their sins AND adopted then in to "Israel".  See the preceding verses for context.